# Creating a war overwrites files that YUICompressed created with the uncompressed files

Tags: java, maven, war, pom.xml

I've been trying to get YUICompress to work with our Maven build process, and so far I haven't had any luck. I see YUICompress actually compress the files, and if I force a stop in the build I see that the files are correctly compressed, but then right at the end where it goes to build the war file, it looks like it copies over all the original files that were uncompressed instead of using the ones that were compressed.

It seems like I must be missing something obvious, but so far I haven't found anything by googling, and no amount of fiddling around seems to be able to point my in the right direction.

Here is the maven build log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ FooBar ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\source\FooBar\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ FooBar ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 18 resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ FooBar ---
[INFO] Compiling 119 source files to C:\source\FooBar\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ FooBar ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\source\FooBar\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ FooBar ---
[INFO] Compiling 34 source files to C:\source\FooBar\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ FooBar ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.1:compress (default) @ FooBar ---
[INFO] context.xml (0b) -> context.xml (0b)[100%]
[WARNING] ...\src\main\webapp\admin\app.js:line -1:column -1:The symbol sidebarController is declared but is apparently never used.
..... Bunch of YUI warnings about using var only once to declare variables.
[WARNING] ...\src\main\webapp\src\Router.js:line -1:column -1:Found an undeclared symbol: _
={activeOrderId:activeOrderId};if( ---> _ <--- .isFinite(itemId)){activeOrderParams.itemId
[INFO] Router.js (10677b) -> Router.js (5963b)[55%]
[INFO] Vent.js (134b) -> Vent.js (87b)[64%]
[INFO] navigation.css (6788b) -> navigation.css (6955b)[102%]
[INFO] style.css (365b) -> style.css (307b)[84%]
[INFO] total input (3477290b) -> output (2399988b)[69%]
[INFO] nb warnings: 4969, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ FooBar ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [FooBar] in [C:\source\FooBar\target\FooBar]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\source\FooBar\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1909 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\source\FooBar\target\FooBar.war
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored
```

Our plugins section from our pom file.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>!test.impl,test*</Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    <!--
                       add ,plugin.xml if it's present i.e.
                       src/main/resources,plugin.xml
                    -->
                    <Include-Resource>src/main/resources</Include-Resource>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working around this issue by adding this to my pom

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceExcludes>**/*.js,**/*.css</warSourceExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but it works for what I needed.